# Problem with Matrix/data-frame looping in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to take years of balance sheet data and determine the percent change of each data point from year to year

The problem is that I don't know how to handle the first year of data as it doesn't have a percent change.

The structure of the data is as follows

```
              2017       2018     2019  
NetIncome     123        156     197
COGS          34         32      36
ETC           23         35      32
```

What is the best way to create a table that shows the percent changes each year that won't attempt to run the first year's data?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take the difference between adjacent years by taking the difference of subset of data without the first column, last column and use `prop.table` to get the percentage

```
cbind(`2017` = 0, prop.table(as.matrix(df1[-1] -df1[-length(df1)]), 1))
```

---

If we need to divide

```
cbind(`2017` = 0,(df1[-1] -df1[-length(df1)])/df1[-length(df1)])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`2017` = c(123L, 34L, 23L), `2018` = c(156L, 32L, 
35L), `2019` = c(197L, 36L, 32L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("NetIncome", 
"COGS", "ETC"))
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow how you are getting the percent change for the second year without the data from the first year

Comment: @Tahum `df1[-1]` removes the first column (in a `data.frame` - if it is matrix `m1[, -1]`) and `df1[-ncol(df1)]` or `df1[-length(df1)]` removes the last column, which makes both the dataset to be of same dimensions.  In `df1[-length(df1)]`, the first column is first column and in `df1[-1]`, it is first, so essentially, we are doing the subtraction between adjacent columns

Comment: @Tahum If this is not your expected, please update your post with the expected output.  That would make it easy to understand what you are up to

Comment: Okay I'm with you now, the only thing I would need to add is the division as (New Number - Old Number)/Old Number is what I'm trying to apply to each datapoint. Thanks for the help!!